# display a listview with different formatted entries

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I want to build a list view which displays "awards" the player has received in the game.

There are many examples out there of how to display a listview with text + icon.
However, in my case I need to vary the icon.

In the case the award is given fro a one-time achievement. In that case I just want the text and the "Trophy" to appear.
In other cases it is awarded for doing something a specified number of times.
In that case I need to include a progress bar.

How can I do the varying layouts within one list view?

---

Update:

Thanks to Leyths it is working (sort of).
Thing is that the ProgressBar is not showing - just its spinner.

This is the row:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwShortMessage"
android:typeface="sans"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwLongMessage"
android:typeface="sans"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/tvwShortMessage"/>
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/pgbAwardProgress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
android:layout_below="@id/tvwLongMessage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)AwardsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.awards_row, parent, false);
    }
    AwardItem award = awards.get(position);
    ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pgbAwardProgress);
    if(award.award_type == PROGRESSIVE) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pb.setMax(award.requirement);
        pb.setProgress(award.current_amount);

    } else {
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvwShortMessage)).
                  setText(MessageBuilder.buildMessage(AwardsActivity.this, award.award_text, 
                          Integer.valueOf(award.requirement).toString()));

    return v;
    }
```

I actually want the opposite - the bar without the spinner.

Is this problem due to the special way this is being displayed or am i doing something wrong with the progress bar?

Resulting screen:

[image]

Comment: very much confusing....provide a wireframe or any sketch for your problem. It would be a better to understand.

Comment: if you want to show a progress bar as image only,then you can have your xml includes image and TextView and change the image as per your requirement for each listitem.but if you really mean progress bar,then it is really hard to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a class which extends a subclass of [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), for example ArrayAdapter, and in your getView() method either inflate one of two different views (with an image and text in your case or text and a progressbar), or inflate one view and then set the visibility of the different view elements using setVisibility() to create the desired final layout.

For example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
            }
            ListObject o = items.get(position);

            if(o.someCondition) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.view_element).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.findViewById(R.id.some_other_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
}
```

Comment: Which constructor do I use for the class I create? Is it irrelevant since I am overriding getView()?

Comment: Try looking at the bottom of [this](http://code.google.com/p/bconnected-gtv/source/browse/android/src/edu/bsu/android/gtv/apps/bconnected/ui/ContentFragment.java?spec=svn1f13a3bdc54fff5afdb55d2be47d122e2cc22ef7&name=1f13a3bdc5&r=1f13a3bdc54fff5afdb55d2be47d122e2cc22ef7) page at the ContentAdapter class, it should provide a good skeleton class for you to build on top of.

Comment: It works except that I am having the problem that the progress bar is not showing properly. All I am getting is the spinner without the bar. See my edit for the code.

Comment: If you mean that the `ProgressBar` is appearing in an indeterminate state (for example a progress bar which gets filled from 0% to 100% hasn't appeared and a spinning 'this will take as long as it takes' wheel is in its place) then you need to call `setIndeterminate(false)` on the ProgressBar.

Comment: From [here](http://bytecrafter.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-horizontal-progress-bar-in.html) it says you need to add in your layout's .xml file for the `ProgressBar` tag the line `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`, replacing the current style.

Comment: Perfect!!! Once I finish it all maybe I will post the whole code somewhere as an example. Where is the best place to put it?

Comment: I'm not the right person to ask that question, but probably a blog post or stick it up on github or a similar public repository.